# CRA latest deployment is not picked by firebase hosting even with service worker no cache changes

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app

I use create react app hosted on firebase hosting.
Even with changes pointed in docs https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#firebase-https-firebasegooglecom the latest changes are not picked.

My firebase.json config file.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "headers": [{ "source": "/service-worker.js", "headers": [{ "key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache" }] }],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help pls

Comment: check for version conflict

Comment: @HashirMalik version conflict??